# Are there any online resources that have a list of post-translational modifications and their molecular weight?

Tags: proteins, database

I am studying a protein and I am interested in learning about all the post-translational modifications that it has (as I am analysing it via Western blot). I have found a list of the post-translational modifications that it has, however, I want to know what are the molecular weights of the post-translational modifications (in daltons/kilodaltons). I have found this [site](https://www.sigmaaldrich.com/life-science/proteomics/post-translational-analysis/phosphorylation/mass-changes.html) but I am not sure what the difference is between 'Monoisotopic Mass Change' and 'Average Mass Change' and what units the values are in.

I was wondering if there are any reliable online resources that have a list of all the post-translational modifications that exist and their associated molecular weights? Any insights are appreciated.

Comment: To a man with a hammer, everything looks like a nail. If you want to know what modifications a protein might have you use the most appropriate method. Western blots of SDS gels isn’t it. Your intelligence is the resource you need to consult. Calculate the molecular weight of an acetyl group and then what increase N-acetylation will have on the molecular weight of your protein. Then determine whether SDS gel electrophoresis can resolve that difference. You have accepted an answer to your question, but it is not an answer to your — or anyone else’s biological problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've found one. Since the differences between the "Monoisotopic" and "Average" columns in the Sigma-Aldrich link you found are extremely low, functionally we can say they are approximately equal. The masses are in atomic mass units, or Daltons.

However, these numbers are from actual mass changes seen in modified peptides analyzed by LC/MS/MS, typically from digested proteins. Mass spec is a highly precise platform, as you can see by the number of decimal places in the numbers in the table. When estimating protein size by Western blot, the margin of error is at least 1 kilodalton for smaller (10-50 kDa) proteins and 5-10 kDa or more for larger ones. Since a single phosphorylation event would only change the mass of a target protein by 0.08 kDa, determining that by Western blot is essentially impossible. However, evidence shows that proteins modified by a single phosphorylation event typically also have (sometimes many) other post-translational modifications (PTMs) as well, including other phospho sites, methylation, acetylation, glycosylation, etc., that can visibly affect a modified protein's mobility in an SDS-PAGE gel.

Another factor to think about is that in denaturing SDS-PAGE gels (which most Western blots are generated from), migration rates are not only influenced by total molecular mass, but also by charge, as the proteins are migrating in an electrical field. When these proteins are linearized by SDS, a charged detergent, their overall charge is roughly proportional to their size. However, charged PTMs like phosphorylation will affect that overall charge, and may modify the migration rate according to that charge *in addition* to their extra mass.

Combine all this together, and you have PTM-modified proteins migrating at somewhat different rates than one might expect based on the physical mass of the modification(s) alone. When you start combining multiple PTMs, especially different kinds of PTMs (phosphorylation and acetylation, for example), it can become very difficult or impossible to predict what the expected apparent molecular masses will be.